# Use javascript variables defined in File 1 in File 2, when File 2 is used in File 1

Tags: javascript, raphael

What I am trying to do is the following. I am writing code for a sketch using `Raphael.js`, in an HTML file. To keep the file cleaner, I want to define the long paths in a separate file `pathsFile.js`, from which I can access the path. Even though I am using `Raphael.js`, I think my question has more to do with Javascript than with `Raphael.js`.

**The following works:**

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">          
        <script src="./raphaelJS/raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="./pathsFile.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="main">

        <div id="figSellerBuyer"></div>
         <script>
            s = 1;
            attrbs = {stroke: "white", "stroke-width": 2};
            pw = 850;
            ph = 450;

            paper = new Raphael('figSellerBuyer', pw*s, ph*s);
                    market = paper.path(paths.marketBoundary);

          </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

where file `pathsFile.js` is:

```
var paths = {
    marketBoundary: "M 20 20 L 500 20 L 500 430 L 20 430 Z"
}
```

**The problem is:**

What I want to do is replace the hard coded numbers in `pathsFile.js` to depend on variables `pw` and `ph` defined in the main HTML file. For example, if I change the `pathsFile.js` to:

```
var ph = 450;
var paths = {
    marketBoundary: "M 20 20 L 500 20 L 500 430 L 20 " + ph-20 + " Z"
}
```

the code still works. But this involves defining `ph` in the `pathsFile.js`. Is there a way I can read the values defined in main HTML file.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - use multiple `<script>` blocks:

```
<script>
   var s = 1;
   var attrbs = {stroke: "white", "stroke-width": 2};
   var pw = 850;
   var ph = 450;
</script>

<script src="./pathsFile.js"></script>

<script>
   var paper = new Raphael('figSellerBuyer', pw*s, ph*s);
           market = paper.path(paths.marketBoundary);
 </script>
```

However, being conscious to [global namespace pollution](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/10/respecting-javascript-global-namespace.html), this could certainly be cleaned up.  A simple example of this would be first declaring `var myConfig = {}`, then assigning all of your variables to `myConfig` - so that only one top-level variable is being used.  (Also, explicitly declare all of your variables with `var`.)

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much. This worked great. Thanks also for the suggestion about the good practice. I am really new to Javascript and this is very helpful.